# Mac OSX get list of applications like that of the force quit application

Tags: macos

I would like to know if there is a way to get a list of applications similar to that of the Force Quit Applications List
[image: Force quit app list image]

I don't know if what I've written so far will enable me to do get such information.

```
extension ViewController: NSTableViewDelegate {

fileprivate enum CellIdentifiers {
    static let NameCell = "cell"
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    var appName: String = ""
    var appIcon: NSImage?

    appName = applications[row].localizedName!
    appIcon = applications[row].icon

    if let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "applicationCell"), owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView {

        cell.textField?.stringValue = appName
        cell.imageView?.image = appIcon ?? nil
        print("created")

        return cell
    }
    return nil
}
```

When I debug, I get all the processes, but I wish only to get a list of apps. This is an example of the results I get:
[image]

We can see that there are the apps, but also all the processes (which I do not wish to have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't explain where you got your `applications[]` array from, but I'm assuming it's an array of `NSRunningApplication` objects obtained via `runningApplications()`.

If you want only "regular" applications—i.e. the kind that the user launches and appear in the dock—you'll probably need to do a little digging.

First, check to see if the application has a `bundleURL`. Regular apps are always in a bundle, and any process without a bundle can be ignored.

You can then use `NSBundle` to read the bundle's `Info.plist` file (see `infoDictionary`). Using this dictionary you can tell if it's a regular application (`CFBundlePackageType` is `APPL`). That test will exclude services, plug-ins, and so on from your list.

You can also tell if it's a "background" app (one that doesn't appear in the dock) by seeing if it has a `LSUIElement` property set to `1`.

That should narrow down the list to just those apps a user would normally interact with.

Comment: How would you get the bundle of another app (as you qrote in paragraph 4)

Comment: You can create a Bundle object for any bundle/package given its URL. See `Bundle(url:)`